# How to pass button's url action to sub instead of function in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm doing a web API project and i'm supposed to pass values from the view page to the sub in the controller to validate the values.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveConsultationFee", New With {.strPVID = Model.LoadPatientBiodata.pvid, .strBillNo = Model.LoadPatientBiodata.pbid, .strRefID = ViewBag.strRefID, .dblAmount = ViewBag.dblTotal, .strRemarks = ViewBag.strCategory})'">Save</button>
```

I put the sub name to the url.action of the button. I know that url action should be used with functions, but how can i pass the values to a sub instead? Because what i had in mind is that, the sub will execute the relevant functions to validate each values. If the function returns a false value, then the sub will exit so that the page will not reload each time i check for the other values.

```
Private Sub SaveConsultationFee(ByVal strPVID As String, ByVal strBillNo As String, ByVal strRefID As String, ByVal dblAmount As Double, ByVal strRemarks As String) 
    If CheckPatientPaymentStatus(strPVID) = False Then
        MsgBox("Patient's bill is settled", vbInformation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '//Check compulsary fields
    '//Check consultation charges
    '//Get cosultant invoice ID

    If strRefID Is Nothing Then
        '// Create New
    Else
        Dim strErr = UpdateCharges(strPVID, strRefID, dblAmount, strRemarks)
    End If

    '//Save diagnosis
    '//Update charges
    '//Update log charges act
End Sub

Private Function CheckPatientPaymentStatus(ByVal strPVID As String) As Boolean
    If strPVID IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Query As String = " SELECT * FROM patientvisit
                                WHERE pvid = '" & strPVID & "'
                                AND paymentstatus <> 'Paid' AND (BillClosed <> 1 OR BillClosed Is Null) "

        Dim Results = dbb.Database.SqlQuery(Of patientvisit)(Query)

        If Results.Count > 0 Then
            CheckPatientPaymentStatus = True
        Else
            CheckPatientPaymentStatus = False
        End If
    Else
        CheckPatientPaymentStatus = True
    End If

    Return CheckPatientPaymentStatus
End Function


Private Function UpdateCharges(ByVal strPVID As String, ByVal strRefID As String, ByVal dblAmount As Double, ByVal strRemarks As String) As String
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim Query = " UPDATE patientbill 
                  SET amount = " & dblAmount & ", remarks = '" & strRemarks & "', UpdOn = GETDATE() 
                  WHERE pvid = '" & strPVID & "' AND refid = '" & strRefID & "' "

    dbb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Query)

err:
    Dim strErr = "Ref '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description

    Return strErr
End Function
```

I tried the code above, but error shows up as shown below:

[image: The resource cannot be found]

I'm still new to MVC. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to invoke an action and then have that action, i.e. that public function, call the sub.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so that means from view's url.action button => controller function(is this action result? or a simple function?) -> controller sub -> controller function -> controller sub for more checking -> etc..like this?

Comment: Your `SaveConsultationFee()` method needs to a `public Function SaveConsultationFee( ... ) As ActionResult` and since your redirecting to it, needs to return something (typically a view). But why are you just sending back the original information your sent to the view in the first place?